# Conditionals with booleans - TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following the condition:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const hasFalsyValue = (
      dropdownValue === undefined
      || dropdownValue === null
    );

    if (hasFalsyValue && !onChangeText) {
      return;
    }

    onChangeText(dropdownValue);
  }, [
    dropdownValue,
    onChangeText,
    inputProps,
  ]);
```

If `hasFalsyValue` is true, then, the effect will return right away. But TS is yelling on me saying the `dropdownValue` can still be `undefined`

[image]

If I extract the conditions from the constant and put it inside the conditional parenthesis, it will work

[image]

Comment: for what it's worth, `if (dropdownValue == null)` performs exactly the same comparison. However you'd still have the TypeScript issue.

Comment: what about `typeof dropdownValue == 'undefined'`?

Comment: @Benchy the `==` (two `=`) comparator for `null` or `undefined` on one side is explicitly specified to *also* test for the other (`undefined` or `null`). So `== null` also tests for `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If `hasFalsyValue` is true, then, the effect will return right away.

No - only when `hasFalsyValue` is true **and** `onChangeText` is falsy. You might have meant

```
const hasFalsyValue = (dropdownValue === undefined || dropdownValue === null);

if (hasFalsyValue || !onChangeText) {
  return;
}

onChangeText(dropdownValue);
```

or

```
const hasFalsyValue = (dropdownValue === undefined || dropdownValue === null);

if (!hasFalsyValue && onChangeText) {
  onChangeText(dropdownValue);
}
```

Btw I'd recommend to shorten this to

```
if (dropdownValue != null) {
  onChangeText?(dropdownValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's almost OK. you misused `&&` and TypeScript is not so smart to pick up variable, so this should work:

#1 Define guard

```
function isDefined<T>(v: T|undefined): v is T {
    return v!= null 
}
```

#2 use it

```
if (!isDefined(dropdownValue) || !onChangeText) {
  return;
}
onChangeText(dropdownValue);
```